# How to bypass only position independent executables (pie) are supported on android N?

Tags: security, lineageos, system-error, 7.1-nougat

How can I bypass

> only position independent executables (pie) are supported

on android N(lineageos 14.1,vega Iron)? 
[This xda thread](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/fix-bypassing-pie-security-check-t2797731/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwjuicrLjfbaAhWKlZQKHV-XB-EQFjACegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2IsSSlu56HDVhjJSXYNzR-&ampcf=1) made me infinite rebooting. Also I cannot rebuild the app.. Please help!

Comment: Usually it is easier to just get an updated version of the binary you want to execute or if the sources are available just compile it using NDK. What do you want to execute that is not PIE enabled?

Comment: @Robert https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.spartacusrex.spartacuside%26hl%3Den%26referrer%3Dutm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dorganic%2526utm_term%253Dterminal%2Bide&ved=2ahUKEwia8p_ekPfaAhUBj5QKHVV8DHIQFjAMegQIABAB&usg=AOvVaw2dqwdMwho62-PUHyNseuYj

Comment: @Robert specifically terminal-gcc, etc. I need gcc that runs on Arm32.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain about gcc. The question should fully describe what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe it willl help. I haven't tried it yet... https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/purifyos-pass-pie-t3651840